# 13.10 Install not picking up hard drive

Tags: installation, hard-drive, 13.10

Trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 on Dell Inspiration laptop but it isn't picking up the hard drive during the install process.

If I Try rather than Install and open GParted it picks up the hard drive fine. Then while in Try I run Install it still does not pick up the hard drive.

It is a SATA 500GB hard drive.

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by running the following command:

`sudo dmride -rE`

Comment: If you've got it working then plz mark it as Answer to help other users who encounter the same issue

Comment: Can't for another 2 days.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot that you need 48 hours. Please note that you do it without fail